# Splitting debian packages. What should their relationships be?

Tags: debian, apt

I had package `foo` which deployed `/usr/lib/libfoo1.so` and `/usr/lib/libfoo2.so`.

I'd like to split `foo` into two packages:  `foo1` and `foo2`, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct relationships.  I think I want to [Replace whole packages, forcing their removal](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#replacing-whole-packages-forcing-their-removal), but that only seems to work when renaming package (not splitting them).

---

This is my test `debian/control`:

```
Source: libfoo
Maintainer: Stewart <stewart@unix.stackexchange.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 11)

Package: foo
Architecture: all
Description: Old package

Package: foo1
Architecture: all
Conflicts: foo
Replaces: foo
Provides: foo

Package: foo2
Architecture: all
Conflicts: foo
Replaces: foo
Provides: foo

Package: bar
Architecture: all
Depends: foo
Description: Old rdepends, don't want this breaking

Package: baz
Architecture: all
Depends: foo1, foo2
Description: New rdepends, this needs to work too
```

Then to test I:

```
dpkg-buildpackage

# Set up an existing system
sudo dpkg -i ../foo_1.0.0_all.deb ../bar_1.0.0_all.deb

# Simulate what will happen during upgrade
sudo dpkg -i ../baz_1.0.0_all.deb ../foo1_1.0.0_all.deb ../foo2_1.0.0_all.deb
```

I'm trying to get a situation where `foo1` and `foo2` are installed, `foo` gets uninstalled, and `bar` and `baz` are both happy.

---

The situation with `{Conflicts,Replaces,Provides}: foo` leads to:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ../foo1_1.0.0_all.deb ../foo2_1.0.0_all.deb ../baz_1.0.0_all.deb 
dpkg: regarding ../foo1_1.0.0_all.deb containing foo1:
 foo1 breaks foo
  foo (version 1.0.0) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive ../foo1_1.0.0_all.deb (--install):
 installing foo1 would break foo, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
dpkg: regarding ../foo2_1.0.0_all.deb containing foo2:
 foo2 breaks foo
  foo (version 1.0.0) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive ../foo2_1.0.0_all.deb (--install):
 installing foo2 would break foo, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Preparing to unpack ../baz_1.0.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking baz (1.0.0) over (1.0.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of baz:
 baz depends on foo1; however:
  Package foo1 is not installed.
 baz depends on foo2; however:
  Package foo2 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package baz (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ../foo1_1.0.0_all.deb
 ../foo2_1.0.0_all.deb
 baz
```

---

The closest I can get is to set `{Conflicts,Replaces,Provides}:` on foo1, but not foo2.  This gives:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ../foo1_1.0.0_all.deb ../foo2_1.0.0_all.deb ../baz_1.0.0_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package baz.
(Reading database ... 538326 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ../baz_1.0.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking baz (1.0.0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package foo1.
dpkg: considering removing foo in favour of foo1 ...
dpkg: yes, will remove foo in favour of foo1
Preparing to unpack ../foo1_1.0.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking foo1 (1.0.0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package foo2.
Preparing to unpack ../foo2_1.0.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking foo2 (1.0.0) ...
Setting up foo1 (1.0.0) ...
Setting up foo2 (1.0.0) ...
Setting up baz (1.0.0) ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#overwriting-files-in-other-packages) provides an example where `foo` is split into `foo` and `foo-data`.  That is the situation which applies here.

We shouldn't actually replace `foo` with a `Provides:` package like expected.  That's because when adding `Provides: foo` to both `foo1` and `foo2`, either package would satisfy `bar`, while in reality bar probably relies on the content of `foo1`, or `foo2`, but not either of them arbitrarily.  Therefore, satisfying `foo` means that you need `foo1` AND `foo2`.  You can only do that if `foo` `Depends: foo1, foo2`.

So the initial control file should look like this:

```
Source: libfoo
Maintainer: Stewart <stewart@unix.stackexchange.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 11)

Package: foo
Architecture: all

Package: bar
Architecture: all
Depends: foo
```

From here, `dpkg -i foo_1.0.0_all.deb bar_1.0.0_all.deb` to set up your initial conditions.  Then change your control file to this:

```
Source: libfoo
Maintainer: Stewart <stewart@unix.stackexchange.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 11)

Package: foo
Architecture: all
Depends: foo1, foo2

Package: foo1
Architecture: all
Breaks: foo (<< 1.1)
Replaces: foo (<< 1.1)

Package: foo2
Architecture: all
Breaks: foo (<< 1.1)
Replaces: foo (<< 1.1)

Package: baz
Architecture: all
Depends: foo1, foo2
```

Then build this, and you'll find that when you install/upgrade `foo`, `foo1`, `foo2`, and `baz`, they will all install properly and they won't break `bar`.